# autocomplete combobox not showing dropdown button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I was practicing an auto-complete combo-box from this link.

http://jsfiddle.net/n7xuD/

```
<select id="myselect" class="combobox">    
<option value="" ></option>
</select>
```

In this demo, I can see dropdown option for the list. I implemented this in my project and there is already bunch of bootstrap classes in my project but still I cannot see this option. Please help me how can I get that?

Thank you

Comment: Thats `jquery-ui` element I guess..

Comment: @bishnu karki i think you must put some code with as your conditions coz in demo it's working as we can see or i can't understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

May be Its not working when jQuery Conflict occur.First check about it.